# changing partition name dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * FROM table partition partition1
```

I would like to make a `for` loop or something that would increment to the next partition automatically after the end of each iteration.

Comment: Which DBMS are you on? Should the table being inserted also be incremented? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I am on oracle, No i have not  tried anything yet. no just the partition, say the table is partitioned by months so it goes from partition1 to partition12

Comment: Are you inserting into `table1` the entire time, or does that increment with the partitions?

Comment: yes i am inserting into table1 all the time

Comment: It might help to know why you want to do this.  If you're trying to copy all the data, leaving out the partitions is usually best.  If you're only looking for a specific set of partitions, when using a condition and partition pruning will usually work best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic SQL, query user_tab_partitions to get the partition names, then loop to construct the query with the returned partition names, and execute the SQL. I'm a little rusty, but something like:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cPart IS
      SELECT partition_name
      FROM user_tab_partitions
      WHERE table_name = 'THE_TABLE';
   vSql VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   FOR rPart in cPart LOOP
      vSQL := 'INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM the_table partition ' || rPart.partition_name;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( vSQL );
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```